# "Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined" when importing mongoose Model from another file

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

In my "User.js" file I created a mongoose model and I am exporting it with "module.exports". When I use the model within the "User.js" file the method ".findOne" works and does not throw an error. However, when I import the model in another file and try to use its methods the error occurs. Does importing a mongoose model into another file somehow make it's methods unable to use?

User.js file...

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const validator = require("validator")

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Field cannot be left blank"],
    unique: [true, "That username is already taken"],
    minlength: [3, "Username must be at least 3 characters"],
    maxlength: [15, "Username cannot exceed 15 characters"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Field cannot be left blank"],
    unique: [true, "That email is already in use"],
    validate: [
      (value) => {
        return validator.isEmail(value)
      },
      "You must enter a valid email",
    ],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: [8, "Password must be at least 8 characters"],
  },
  cart: Array,
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", userSchema)

let User = function (data) {
  this.data = data
}

module.exports = { User, UserModel }
```

Pants.js file...

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const { UserModel } = require("./User")

const pantsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  category: String,
  iconCode: Number,
})

const PantsModel = mongoose.model("pant", pantsSchema)

const Pants = function () {
  this.data = ""
}

Pants.addToCart = function (_id, userId) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let user = await UserModel.findOne({ _id: userId }) //this is where the error occurs
    let item = await PantsModel.findOne({ _id })
    console.log(users)
  })
}

module.exports = Pants
```

So again, all the model methods work when I am using the UserModel in the same file it was created in but when I try to use in a separate file, the error occurs.

Comment: Can you print the `UserModel` to check what it is?

Comment: It prints "Model { user }"